# case when combination by product

Tags: sql, oracle

I have many products on my table. And I want to be able to analyze how many of these products are used together. I want to show the most used among these products, I created a table as follows;
My Table;

```
Customer_id  Product Count(product)     Product Amount  Total Amount per Customer
1               A      3                         10               20
1               B      3                          5               20
1               C      3                          5               20
2               D      2                         20               30
2               E      2                         10               30 
3               A      2                          5               35
3               F      2                         30               35
4               B      1                         40               40
5               D      2                         5                10  
5               E      2                         5                10
6               A      2                         3                6
6               F      2                         3                6
```

the result I want;

```
COUNT( DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID)    SUM(TOTAL AMOUNT)  PRODUCT_COUNT  PRODUCT_BUNDLE
           1                       20                 3                A&B&C
           2                       40                 2                 D&E
           2                       41                 2                 A&F
           1                       10                 1                  B
```

Comment: Do not replace text (which can be copy/pasted) with images hidden behind links (which we may not be able to see and cannot copy/paste the data from).

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate twice:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(customer_id),
       product_count,
       SUM(total_amount),
       product_bundle
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         LISTAGG(product, '&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product) AS product_bundle,
         COUNT(product) AS product_count,
         SUM(product_amount) AS total_amount
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY customer_id
)
GROUP BY product_count, product_bundle
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table table_name (Customer_id, Product, Product_Amount) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'D', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'E', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'A',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'F', 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'B', 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'D',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'E',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'A',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F',  3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) | PRODUCT_COUNT | SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) | PRODUCT_BUNDLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 20 | A&B&C |
| 2 | 2 | 40 | D&E |
| 2 | 2 | 41 | A&F |
| 1 | 1 | 40 | B |

If you only want bundles then use `HAVING COUNT(product) > 1` in the inner query (or `WHERE product_count > 1` in the outer query).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6R6ejtZs)